# VSTS Copy File To Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using VSTS to build my Xamarin Forms App for iOS - I've got it building and publishing the artifacts.

At the moment I use an Azure Blob to host the ipa - I would like to add a step to the build process to copy to the blob.  So far I've tried:

- Azure File Copy
- cURL
- Copy Files (Azure File Share)

However nothing has worked.  Has anyone got this working?

Comment: You can use azure power shell to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't think Powershell is available on the Mac Build Agent - A supported task execution handler was not found. This error usually means the task does not carry an implementation that is compatible with your current operating system. Contact the task author for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [VSTS Shell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/shell-script) to run a script on the Macos that upload the .ipa file to the Blob container. A sample script here below.

Please note that:

- all the capital letter variables' values in the script should be passed by the task to the script as arguments (so you need to fix this sample script);
- you need to install python3 on the Macos machine: `homebrew install python3`
- you need to install the Azure SDK for Python, in particular: 
    `sudo pip3 install azure-storage` and `sudo pip3 install table`

Sample script:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import tables
import os
import sys
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

output_blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME,account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
localfileprocessed = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),LOCALFILENAME) #assuming file is in current working directory

try:
  output_blob_service.create_container(CONTAINERNAME, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)
  output_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME, localfileprocessed,
    content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/octet-stream'))

except:
  print ("Something went wrong with uploading to the blob:"+ BLOBNAME)
```